# my switch on/off bulb function does not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make simple switch bulb on/off with one button. But it didn't work.
my html code :

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img src="bulb-off.jpg" class="bulb"></img>
    <button class="btn"> Switch on/off </button>
</div>


<script src="lightbulb.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is JS code:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let bulb = document.querySelector('img');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (bulb.src === 'bulb-off.jpg') {
        bulb.src = 'bulb-on.jpg';
    } else {
        bulb.src = 'bulb-off.jpg';
    }
});
```

my picture are on the same files. my button function is also working when I console.log it. But it didn't work with the changing bulb picture to make it on/off.

Comment: Did you get any error like the image not found?? It works here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/qBONYrz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your comparison `bulb.src === 'bulb-off.jpg'` is not correct. You're checking only for the name of the image, but in reality `src` is the whole path to the image. In order to fix the issue you could find if the name of the image is in the `src`. Something like:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
let bulb = document.querySelector("img");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (bulb.src.includes("bulb-off.jpg")) {
    bulb.src = "bulb-on.jpg";
  } else {
    bulb.src = "bulb-off.jpg";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="bulb-off.jpg" class="bulb" />
  <button class="btn">Switch on/off</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why this line is needed ```bulb.src.indexOf("bulb-off.jpg") >= 0)``` ?? It already works for his same code with external image link here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/qBONYrz .. So I think image path would not correct..

Comment: Your code is very different from OP's code, they are not checking for the full path of the image as you are. That's the problem and that's why that line is needed.

Comment: My code is same as OP's code except the image path.. But yes you may be right that comparison of the path might be wrong in the question..

Comment: "except the image path", that's the whole point :) -- the OP is only checking for the image name, whereas they should be checking for the full image path. Using `.includes()` we can check for a partial path and therefore it works for the OP. In your case, you're already checking for the full path, so it's different. `.src` will return the full path... even though it might just look like a partial path in the `img` element. It's confusing I know :)

Comment: Instead of adding a link, upload an image to your codepen, then add the relative path to it and try the comparsion. It will fail, because `.src` will return the whole path.

Comment: Yup.. So point here is whether we need to check for whole path or else if partial path , using ```includes()``` as like you mentioned..

Comment: Exactly, `bulb.src` gives us the full image path, but OP only wants to know the name of the image. So, with `.includes()` we are just checking if in that full path there exists the name of the image being checked.

Comment: I understood very well. Thank you Luis. Thank you also Murugan.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this snippet to see a working example:

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/on-off-icon-vector-eps-600w-1355996534.jpg" class="bulb" width="100" height="100"></img>
    <button class="btn"> Switch on/off </button>
</div>


<script>
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let bulb = document.querySelector('img');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (bulb.src === 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/on-off-icon-vector-eps-600w-1355996534.jpg') {
        bulb.src = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/start-power-button-icon-vector-260nw-760464229.jpg';
    } else {
        bulb.src = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/on-off-icon-vector-eps-600w-1355996534.jpg';
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```